# Crossfilter get .top of dataset with negative numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to get the top value of a dataset that contains negative numbers (sometimes all negatives).  When I group using .reduceSum, the .top value is never below 0.  How can I use .reduce instead of .reduceSum to include negative numbers?

```
s.topTempGroup = s.temp1ByTimeDim.group().reduce(
            function(p,v) {
                return p + v.tmp1;
            },
            function(p,v) {
                return p - v.tmp1;
            },
            function() { return 0;}
        );

s.topTemp = s.topTempGroup.top(1)[0].value;
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you provide a complete example, including data, the code to generate a result, and your expected result (which I assume is different from what your code is providing)? A working example on JSfiddle or a similar platform would be even better.

Comment: I have a dataset that contains a temperature field.  Based on the current filtered data, I would like to select the highest temperature value which may be negative in some cases.  I'm selecting this top value using "s.topTempGroup.top(1)[0].value;", in most cases it works fine, but when the number should be a negative value it displays "0".

Comment: I see. That's because your empty groups have values of 0, which are larger than your negative values. I'd suggest re-scaling your temperatures so that they are always positive values. There are a few other ways of dealing with this by using a special value like -Infinity as your default value, keeping track of counts, and then handling the 0-count case specially in your aggregation functions, but they are more complicated.

Comment: Keep in mind that Math.abs only helps if all you are sure all your values are negative or all your values are positive, in which case there are better solutions. Why not re-scale?

Comment: The question is really, really difficult to understand... Are you looking for .bottom()???